# How to provision search navigation nodes using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-2013, csom

I need to provision search navigation nodes for SharePoint 2013 webs *without* using server-side code.

The server-side object model includes the following in the Navigation object on an SPWeb:

- TopNavigationBar
- QuickLaunch
- *SearchNav*

SearchNav is the class that allows adding search navigation nodes, but in CSOM it is omitted.

Perhaps that functionality is in a different class. Does anybody know how to do this client-side?